# Swift Natural Language sentiment score not recognising entire string using .document

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the sentiment score of an entire string, which is the behaviour I'm expecting when using the `.document` unit type in the code below (as per [these](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nltokenunit) docs), however this does not return any sentiment value at all and always defaults to 0.

Using `.paragraph` or `.word` unit types *does* return a sentiment score, however only for the first paragraph/word which is not what I'm after.

Separate to the code below I have also tried using the `.document` unit type with `NLTokenizer` to see if in this case the whole string would be recognised as `.document`, and this worked, so this seems to be an issue specific to `.sentimentScore` or `NLTagger`.

```
import SwiftUI
import NaturalLanguage

struct SentimentView: View {
    
    @State var text:String = "I enjoy drinking water.\nAnd I love drinking coffee."
    @State var sentimentScore = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(sentimentScore)")
            .onAppear(perform: {
                let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.sentimentScore])
                tagger.string = text
                let (sentiment, _) = tagger.tag(at: text.startIndex, unit: .document, scheme: .sentimentScore)
                let score = Double(sentiment?.rawValue ?? "0") ?? 0
                sentimentScore = score
            })
    }
}

struct SentimentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SentimentView()
    }
}
```